# How to make a class configurable without adding any code?

Tags: java, configuration, annotations, libraries

I would like to be able to write (in Java) something like the following:

```
public class A implements MagicallyConfigurable {

    @configuration_source_type{"xml"}
    @configuration_dir{"some/rel/path/"}

    /* or maybe some other annotations specifying a db-based configuration etc. */

    int length = 4 /* some kind of default */;
    char c = '*' /* some kind of default */;

    @do_not_configure
    String title;

    A(String title) {

        /* possibly, but hopefully no need to, something like:
        configure();
        call here. */

        this.title = title;
    }

    void goForIt() {
        System.out.println(title);
        for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

and for it to work as expected. That is, the only thing I would need to initialize fields based on a configuration would be adding some annotations, implementing an interface and possibly making a single function call (but hopefully without it).

I'm sure this is theoretically doable, the question is whether there's an existing library/framework/add-on/thingie which enables it. (Maybe Apache commons.configuration somehow? Haven't worked with it before.)

Comment: Off topic, but I'm just curious; The constructor to A takes a string argument.  Why would you want to configure that?  If class B creates A it needs to give in a title.  Why would you want to override that value with configuration?  That would certainly not be what class B expects (that the title changes).

Comment: I don't want to configure that, that's why I marked it as `@unconfigurable`...

Comment: True enough, but inside the constructor you still have `configure(title);` (which is commented out, but indicates that you want it to be run behind the scenes).  Nevermind, I see that in principle we agree.  Sorry I can't answer your main question ...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to use Spring 3.0 EL. An example can be found [here](http://springinpractice.com/2008/12/02/new-stuff-in-spring-30/), but what it basically boils down to is that you can do the following:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.databaseName}")
public void setDatabaseName(String dbName) { ... }
```

And your properties will be automatically set. This will work on setters and on properties.