# How can I have my command-line arguments parsed automagically using annotations?

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, annotations, arguments

I'd like something like the following to work:

```
public class A {
    @command_line_arg{"argname1"}
    static boolean x;

    @command_line_arg{"argname2"}
    static List<String> y;

    void main(String[] args) {
        /* perhaps a call such as parseArgs(); here */
        System.out.println("got argname1 = " + x);
        System.out.println("got argname2 = " + y);
    }
}
```

What library do I need to use?

(somewhat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14622549/1593077).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(based on @fge's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674887/1593077).)

One can use [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) with statics:

```
public class A {

    @Parameter(names = "-argname1")
    static boolean x;
    @Parameter(names = "-argname2", variableArity = true)
    static List<String> y;

    @Parameter
    public static List<String> remainingParameters;

    void main(String[] args) {
        new JCommander(A.class.newInstance(), args);
        System.out.println("got argname1 = " + x);
        System.out.println("got argname2 = " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to JCommander documentation, your variables shouldn't be static, but rather instance variables. I'm guessing that could be a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

[JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) may be of some use to you. It uses annotations to describe all command line arguments and generates options/help text for you.

Quoting the example found on the web site:

```
public class JCommanderExample {
  @Parameter
  private List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Parameter(names = { "-log", "-verbose" }, description = "Level of verbosity")
  private Integer verbose = 1;

  @Parameter(names = "-groups", description = "Comma-separated list of group names to be run")
  private String groups;

  @Parameter(names = "-debug", description = "Debug mode")
  private boolean debug = false;
}
```

Comment: And will this work with static variables as well? I only need to run the main method in my app class...

Comment: Not that I know of... But you can just do `new Main()` in your `main()` method and run it. You will only have one instance at run time, so that's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [klab-commons-cli](https://code.google.com/p/klab-commons-cli/), it adds annotations to Apache commons-cli; there is no distribution jar, you just use the source code. An alternative, which doesn't leverage commons-cli, but provides a distribution library, is [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/).

Comment: The downloads section there seems to be empty. Do I have to use the sources?

Comment: I've edited my answer, if you need a jar there is an alternative, it doesn't leverage commons-cli, however it's as valid as the other one.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of the first over the second?

Comment: The first is a layer over Apache commons-cli, a commonly used and appreciated library, anyway both are valid solutions.